# What is the mean of '(void) (_p)'

Tags: c++

our code has a line like:

```
#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(_p) (void) (_p)

STATUS RequestHandler(Request *request)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(request);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is the mean of UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER, why translate the 'request' to '(void) (request)'

Thanks!:)

Comment: To prevent compiler warnings about unused variables

Comment: `(void)(_p)` has the effect of evaluating the value of `_p`, and converting it to `void`.   The conversion has the effect of discarding the value.  In your case, it is also used to suppress compiler diagnostics about arguments of a function that are unused.    Since evaluation of a raw pointer has no side effects, the net effect of `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(request)` is to evaluate the value of `request` and discard that value - and most compilers (if optimisation is enabled) are smart enough to omit the statement entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to compile this code

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
}
```

with [gcc -Werror -Wall](https://godbolt.org/z/c7T5Pd4jb) you get an error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:3:9: error: unused variable 'x' [-Werror=unused-variable]
    3 |     int x = 0;
      |         ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:3:9: error: unused variable 'x' [-Werror=unused-variable]
    3 |     int x = 0;
      |         ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The old-fashioned way to silence that warning (treated as error here) is to write

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    (void)(x);
}
```

However, since C++17 there is the attribute [`[maybe_unused]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused). Using that gcc does not produce an error with `-Wall -Werror` for this:

```
int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] int x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like GCC really stresses the "maybe" part. https://godbolt.org/z/qvKe66f1x So shouting about `x` is legit. It's unused period. Probably good to remove it rather than use a macro hack.

Comment: GCC only produces an error in your answer because of typos.  The attribute is `[[maybe_unused]]`, not `[[maybe-unused]]` or `[[maybe_ununsed]]`.